# Find Position of Value in numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to find the position in the Array called ImageArray

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import numpy as np

ImageLocation = Image.open("images/numbers/0.1.png")

#Creates an Array [3d] of the image for the colours
ImageArray = np.asarray(ImageLocation)
ArrayRGB = ImageArray[:,:,:3]
#Removes the Alpha Value from the output

print(ArrayRGB)
#RGB is output

print(round(np.mean(ArrayRGB),2))
ColourMean = np.mean(ArrayRGB)
#Outputs the mean of all the values for RGB in each pixel
```

This code searches each point individually in the Array and if it above the mean its supposed to become 255 if its less 0. How can I find the Position in the Array so I can edit its Value.

```
for Row in ArrayRGB:
    for PixelRGB in Row:
        #Looks at each pixel individually
        print(PixelRGB)
        if(PixelRGB > ColourMean):
            PixelRGB[PositionPixel] = 255
        elif(PixelRGB < ColourMean):
            PixelRGB[PositionPixel] = 0
```

Comment: ```PixelRGB[PixelRGB > ColourMean] = 255```?

Comment: and `PixelRGB[PixelRGB < ColourMean] = 0`

Comment: Or as a lazy one-liner: `PixelRGB  = (PixelRGB > ColourMean) * 255`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example, let's consider this array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Now, let's apply your transformation to it:

```
>>> np.where(a>a.mean(), 255, 0)
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255]])
```

The general form for `np.where` is `np.where(condition, x, y)`.  Wherever `condition` is true, it returns `x`.  Wherever `condition` is false, it returns `y`.